# Set window border radius in tauri apps

Tags: javascript, css, rust, tauri

How can I round the corners of a Tauri application window? I've tried several approaches, but none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some of the approaches you tried?

Answer (score 3):

*Warning: MacOS Only*

I'm gonna leave this here for anyone using Vibrancy plugin, there is a method to do this, it's just not documented well enough. I had to dig to find it, and it's simple

```
 apply_vibrancy(&spotlight_window, NSVisualEffectMaterial::HudWindow, None, Some(16.0))
        .expect("Unsupported platform! 'apply_vibrancy' is only supported on macOS");
```

`Some(16.0)` is key here. that's the roundness value in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Small tweak to gaandurian answer for clarity.  If you're using `window_vibrancy`,  I suggesting using their `main.rs` example within their [repo](https://github.com/tauri-apps/window-vibrancy/blob/dev/examples/tauri/src-tauri/src/main.rs).  Heres the code I used to get it to work:

```rust
// Copyright 2019-2022 Tauri Programme within The Commons Conservancy
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

#![cfg_attr(
  all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
  windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

use tauri::Manager;
use window_vibrancy::{apply_blur, apply_vibrancy, NSVisualEffectMaterial};

fn main() {
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .setup(|app| {
      let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

      #[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
      apply_vibrancy(&window, NSVisualEffectMaterial::HudWindow, None, Some(16.0))
        .expect("Unsupported platform! 'apply_vibrancy' is only supported on macOS");

      #[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
      apply_blur(&window, Some((18, 18, 18, 125)))
        .expect("Unsupported platform! 'apply_blur' is only supported on Windows");

      Ok(())
    })
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems there isn't a method to make the window rounded.
But you can use the following methods to make window round (just in view)

0. remove title bar & make tauri window transparent

```
{
  "windows":[
    {
      "decorations": false,
      "transparent": true
    }
  ]
}
```

1. configure css

```css
    #app {
        border-radius: 50px;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: hey, what element has selector ```#app``` in your example?

Comment: <body>
    **<div id="app"></div>**
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>

Answer (score 1):

Set window `transparent` property to `true` in `tauri.conf.json`:

```
"windows": [
  {
    "decorations": false,
    "transparent": true
  }
]
```

Add `border-radius` to element (for example: `<header>` and `<footer>` element) in CSS. The `<body>` should be transparent background and you should use a custom title bar.